GE Dishwasher GDF520PSF2SS Leaking Under Handle Area Near Top of Door
With my new home came a 10 yr old stainless steel GE Dishwasher (Model #: GDF520PSF2SS) that has run perfectly since I moved in a year ago. Recently the dishwasher started to leak near the lower corners so I replaced the gasket seal that goes around the inside area of the tub. I also purchased a lower gasket that I will be replacing at the bottom of the door. I have a new issue with the dishwasher leaking a small, continuous stream of water from the handle area (near top of the door). This may be the gasket on the inside of the door but I'm hoping someone may have experienced this and can help me figure out if that's it.
I removed the vent cover and there is no gunk or debris. I can't see any debris in the drain pipe area and have cleaned both the fine and extra fine filters.

A photo or two of the area would help you out here.
